# MS Access Automatically Generate Random Number

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I want to generate a 6-digit random number in a table row in MS Access, is it possible?

I've tried to make a random number for a user's unique ID in a table, but sometimes it generates a negative number like `-43543435`.

Comment: How do you make this random number?

Answer (score 3):

You can create random numbers between limits with this:

```
Int((maxlimit - minlimit + 1) * Rnd + minlimit)
```

In your case, you want a 6 digit number, so:

```
minlimit = 100000
```

and

```
maxlimit = 999999
```

So:

```
Int(900000 * Rnd + 100000)
```

You can find more about the function `Rnd` here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rnd-function-503cd2e4-3949-413f-980a-ed8fb35c1d80

Comment: Where i write the code? In query design or vba code

Comment: You can use it in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

> sometimes it generates a negative number like -43543435

That's by design. A *random autonumber* can take any value within the range of a Long.

It should make no difference to you, as the value of the ID in any case should be meaningless as its only purpose is to identify the record uniquely and doesn't have to be displayed for the user.

If you wish to apply random numbers to the records for the purpose of sorting, you can study the methods in my article:

[Random Rows in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33030/Random-Rows-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

If you don't have an account, browse to the link: Read the full article.